# jQuery UI: Resizable: catch the resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I have a div which is resizable and now I want to edit a cookie when this box is resized/when the user finished resizing. (I have the cookie plugin)

How can I do this?

PS: I have multiple `.div`'s with different id's.

```
<div class="div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="div" id="div2"></div>
```

**My Code which doesn't work (it doesn't save the cookie)**

```
$( ".div" ).resizable({
    handles: \'s\',
    onResize: function(size) {
        $.cookie("div_height", this.height);
    }
});
```

Comment: please explain *doesnt work*. Does it not resize or does it not save the cookie? Please be more specific

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop). The event to be used is `stop` and not `onResize`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code

```
$( ".div" ).resizable({
   handles: \'s\',
   stop: function(e,ui) {
      $.cookie("div_height", ui.size.height);
   }
});
```

Comment: This works so far, but the cookie value is then "undefined". The `this.height` parnt isn't correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working js fiddle to capture the resize event, having another example, but it perfectly suitable for you: http://jsfiddle.net/byrgv6j4/1/

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      //console.log(e);  
      //console.log(ui);
      console.log(ui.size.height);
    }
});
```

You must get the `ui.size.height` if you want to get the height of the current state of the element.